# Getting udev to recognize unique usb drives from a set - with the same uuid and labels? RHEL7

Tags: linux, usb, udev, rhel-7

I'm trying to configure udev on RHEL7 so usb flash drives are assigned specific /dev names (ie.  /dev/backup1 , /dev/backup2....) for specific flash drives - I realize I can't control the /dev/sdx assignments but am trying to set up automated symlinks using udev rules.

blkid gives me:

```
/dev/sdi1: LABEL="Samsung USB" UUID="64A5-F009" TYPE="exfat"
/dev/sdj1: LABEL="Samsung USB" UUID="64A5-F009" TYPE="exfat"
/dev/sdk1: LABEL="Samsung USB" UUID="64A5-F009" TYPE="exfat"
```

I wanted to do something like: in my rules file

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM=="/lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --replace-whitespace --device=%N", RESULT=="64A5-F009", SYMLINK+="backupkeya%n"
```

but since all three usb flash drives have the same uuid - I wanted specific flashdrives to get linked to specific virtual device names. So If I plugged in the one labeled "drive2" it would link to /dev/backupkeyb.  Right now we have 3 flash drives - but want to expand to about 8.

udevadm gives me some uniqueness...

```
[root@alpha2 mnt]# udevadm info /dev/sdg | grep "ID_SERIAL_SHORT"
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0305119070014252
[root@alpha2 mnt]# udevadm info /dev/sdi | grep "ID_SERIAL_SHORT"
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0330219070015017
[root@alpha2 mnt]# udevadm info /dev/sdj | grep "ID_SERIAL_SHORT"
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0305119070014208
```

I changed my udev rule to read  (/etc/udev/rules.d/99-symlink.rules)

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM=="/bin/udevadm info --name=%N", RESULT=="0305119070014208", SYMLINK+="backupkeyc%n"
```

however, when I plugged in the key that had the ...4208 serial number - no /dev/backupkeyc symlink was created. I suspect it's because the output of the udevadm statement wasn't an exact match for my RESULT==

I created a script /usr/local/udevinfo and changed the PROGRAM=="/usr/local/udevinfo %N" as below as so to not clutter the udev rule...after I put in the flash drive - no symlink - but more importantly there was nothing in the /tmp/passeddata which should have contained the device name - so it looks like the udev rule never ran?

```
echo "$1" >> /tmp/passeddata
udevadm info --name=$1 | grep "ID_SERIAL_SHORT" | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Am I missing anything? any easier way to go about what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @grawity - bingo. changing the PROGRAM== and RESULT== combo over to the ENV{}== formatting working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it wasn't an exact match, because 'udevadm info' outputs a whole lot of information – not just the serial number.

However, anything you see in 'udevadm info' is *set by* udev rules themselves (often by invoking udev built-ins). So the serial number is already usable as `ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="..."` without having to call an external program. (That's what the "E:" prefix actually indicates.)

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="0305119070014208", SYMLINK+="backupkeyc"
```

(In fact, it is possible that 'udevadm info' wouldn't work *at all* during rule processing. A common mistake in udev rules is to try using tools which themselves only get information from the "rules finished" signals.)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @grawity's answer as to not use a script for such solution but directly the env. But for the other aspects:

The syntax for program is correct that way You wrote and works. Maybe You mean nothin is in the file that the file does not get created? So it's missing the shebang line (as in your snippet) or execute permissions? Otherwise it should work that way - AND You even doe not need to pass any argument as all the information udev knows about is available in the environment as variables. So script can access them when called by udev rule PROGRAM statement.

But it should be much more convenient and generic to follow a different approach:
Do not use the Serial Numbers of the device but assign them a UUID or Partition Label (or both to lower the probability anything else is inserted which has same UUID or Partition label). So just relabel the partitions or reformat them to get set a new "UUID". It's also possible to patch the UUID information within existing partition if You do not want to reformat (I don't know about a tool that does this for You but it's really simple to write Your own).
That way You could replace the targets without modifying Your system. Or add more sticks to a pool for example.
In that case You could even prefer to use a small PROGRAM script that translates partition label of a specific format to a symlink name of a specific format.
Another (if feasible the most standard conforming way) might be to use a GPT on the devices and assign some specific partition-type and -UUID combination for Your use case - possibly addtitional partition name.

Comment: the script worked when run manually.  I gave it the same rights and ownership as the udevadm program.  what I was trying to figure out was whether %N was sending /dev/sdx or just sdx since if /dev/sdx then you would just put that in the udevadm commandline, but if it was just sdx then you needed to use --name=  I later changed the script to not use --name= as when I used the test mode of udevadm it kept saying the running of the script failed - possibly because it was in /usr/local vs /sbin or /bin??

Comment: I thought about setting a partition UUID - but wasn't sure if that would trigger a symlink also for the root device. so I'd get a symlink for /dev/sdx and /dev/sdx1 or just a symlink for /dev/sdx1.  Since they are only 128gb drives - I left the native filesystem (exfat) in case I needed to quickly pull the data using a windows machine.

Comment: For me same script setups are working. If You can execute script as command (so not as argument to shell home some are executing scripts but plain).

Comment: The script will trigger for both separately if You have no filter before (for the device and if existing for the partitions on it). With UID You tag only the partitions or more specific the filesystems if You do not opt to using GPT with real partition GUIDs and labels where You would have both).